# centered page with non scrolling sidebars

Tags: html, css, .net, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying, but struggling to get this layout going using twitter bootstrap, what I need is a centered page with two side columns that don't scroll with the page but a center column that does.

for reference the black displays the entire screen space, with blue showing body content, two grey boxes being non scrolling, but maroon scrolling normally as it is the main content for the page

[image]

Setting any column with position fixed makes them overlap, and attempting to use a traditional sidebar takes it to the edge of the view space, which is also undesired. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The example shows to use the universal scollbar (on the right side of browser frame, rather than in the middle), live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hm4do8mg/

HTML

```
<div class="left">
    <p>left</p>
</div>

<div class="midd">
    <p style="height:2000px;">midd</p>
    <p>bottom</p>
</div>

<div class="righ">
    <p>righ</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, p {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}

.left,
.righ {
    background: lightgrey;
    position: fixed;
}

.left {
    width: 20%;
}

.midd {
    background: paleturquoise;
    width: 60%;
    position: relative;
    left: 20%;
    top: 0;
}

.righ {
    width: 20%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

The layout you asked, is kind of old fashion style like `<iframe>`. You can also use `<table>` to do it, it's the most solid, and easiest way to me (ignore it if you need a mobile version).

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle that can help you achieve this. But I haven't used Bootstrap. You can easily make these changes on bootstrap grid.

[**JSFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rhx5aee5)

Answer (score 0):

I think this could fit your needs. It's not perfect, but it's a starting point.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="first col-xs-3">
        <div class="fixed">
            <p>Fixed</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 scroll">
        <p>PUT A NOVEL IN HERE</p>
    </div>
    <div class="second col-xs-3">
        <div class="fixed second">
            <p>Fixed</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 html, body {
    background:#CCCCCC;
    height:100%;
}
.container, .row {
    height:100%;
}
.fixed {
    height:100%;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    position:fixed;
    width:20%;
}
.scroll {
    height:100%;
    background:#000000;
    overflow:auto;
}
.second.fixed{
    margin-left:-15px;
}
```

**DEMO**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c0kz36nx/2/)